# how to get jsp's predefined variables in tag handlers

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

I am writing a JSP page with custom tags. Normally the page would be like:

```
<h1>Welcome <%request.getRemoteUser()%> <h1>
```

I want to introduce custom tags for this instead of having to write script lets. So I decided to write one tag handler. The problem is I do not know a way to get request object in tag handler.

My tag handler looks like:

```
UserNameTagHandler extends TagSupport{
    public int doTag() throws JspException {
        String userName = request.getRemoteUser();    //How can I get the correct request object.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend TagSupport and then use pageContext variable.

```
HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) pageContext.getRequest();
```

Comment: I am extending `TagSupport` but can you expand on how to use PageContext variable?

Comment: Ref this http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/jsp/PageContext.html

Comment: Surprisingly was looking at the same page. Thanks!